# How to Send a notification when a post is updated on Wordpress Gutenberg

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

I want to create a function that connect my Wordpress site to an external API when a post is updated. I aready did the method by using the `post_updated` Hook, but I would like to send a notification to the WP editor. Since on Gutemberg the post requests are made using AJAX, I'm not sure how to display notification without refreshing the page. Do you know if there is a Hook to send these notifications? Thanks in advance

I spect to send a notification to Wordpress Editor

Answer (score 0):

In the block Editor, the [Notices Data API](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/data/data-core-notices/) is used to create custom Notifications with JS/AJAX for events like when a post is published, display errors or warnings. Below is the example usage given in the [WordPress Gutenberg Notifications](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/how-to-guides/notices/#notices-in-the-block-editor) guide:

```js
( function ( wp ) {
    wp.data.dispatch( 'core/notices' ).createNotice(
        'success', // Can be one of: success, info, warning, error.
        'Post published.', // Text string to display.
        {
            isDismissible: true, // Whether the user can dismiss the notice.
            // Any actions the user can perform.
            actions: [
                {
                    url: '#',
                    label: 'View post',
                },
            ],
        }
    );
```

Depending on what you need notices for, [withNotices](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/components/with-notices/) (a Higher Order Component) could be of interest to you. There is also the ability to [lock/prevent post saving](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/data/data-core-editor/#lockpostsaving) which can be used in conjunction with your notice/s.