# Showing notices in the Block Editor as action response

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

I am developing a Wordpress plugin, that executes a function on the `transition_post_status` hook.

When the function gets executed, I want to notify the current editor user what happened on save.

For simplicity, I just added one case here:

```php
add_action('transition_post_status' function($new_status, $old_status, $post) {
    if ($old_status === 'publish' && $new_status === 'draft') {
        // logic for sending an email here
        // show "I messaged your admin" here
    }
});
```

My ideas were to modify the post response somehow or to write my message to a post meta field, however, when my message is in post meta, how am I able to retrieve in the editor and render a new component with it? The second problem would occure with the post response approach as well.

Comment: This [similar question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74996032/how-to-send-a-notification-when-a-post-is-updated-on-wordpress-gutenberg) seems close to what you are looking to do?